# How to check order-status of each items individually particular order in Magento-2.1.12?

Tags: magento-2.1, order-status

Suppose i have one order with multiple items.How to check order-status of each items individually  particular order in Magento-2.1.12?

Comment: Anybody help me ..

Comment: PLease provide me solution asap.